# Trouble parsing JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am playing around with parsing JSON in jQuery and I am having trouble.  I want to check the value of 'time' in the JSON object.  Here is my trial function:

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'do_chat.php5',
     type: 'post',
     data: ({'message':'','poster':poster,'logged_in':logged_in}),
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data) {
       $.each(data, function(interval, message) {
       if(message['time']) {
     $('#chatWindow').append('<p>hi</p>');
       }
 });
     }
     });
```

The string being returned from my server looks like:

{"poster":"","message":"No messages!","time":1256084677}

I am not sure of the syntax of $.each.  I am using PHP to encode the JSON string, which started life as a php assoc array.  I'm sure my mistakes are plenty and any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit: follow up question** - how do I make PHP generate a JSON array?  At the moment I use this to generate the single object:

```
$messages = mysqli_fetch_assoc($new_res);
 $msg = $messages["content"];
 $who = $messages["poster"];
 $time = $messages["time_added"];
$message = array(
  'poster' => $who,
  'message' => $msg,
  'time' => $time
);

echo json_encode($message);
```

But if I were to get more than one row from my database query, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are returning a single JSON Object `{"poster":"","message":"No messages!","time":1256084677}`, but you are then iterating through it with `$.each`.

`$.each` expects an array, and since you are not returning an array, the `$.each` is looping through the elements of your JSON object instead.

To fix your code, you need to either make sure your server is returning an array, like:
`[{"poster":"","message":"No messages!","time":1256084677}]`

*or*

Remove the `$.each`, so that you have:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'do_chat.php5',
    type: 'post',
    data: ({'message':'','poster':poster,'logged_in':logged_in}),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data['time']) {
            $('#chatWindow').append('<p>hi</p>');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'do_chat.php5',
     type: 'post',
     data: ({'message':'','poster':poster,'logged_in':logged_in}),
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data) {
         if (typeof data.time != 'undefined') {
             $('#chatWindow').append('<p>' + data.poster + ' - ' + data.message + '</p>');
         }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I end up using a JSON parser from http://json.org:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getData.asmx/retrieveSubcontractorList",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{}",
    success: function(result2) {
        var toolsData = JSON.parse(result2.d);
```

The trick was that the data is actually in a property called `d`.